# How to make csv or excel exactly like this json using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv comma delimited or .xlsx that needs to be converted into a json exactly like shown below using Python. How can I make this parsing right ? I tried many different approaches but never archived this format.

| Category | code | brand | model | size | capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phone | 234 | Samsung | Galaxy S21 | S | 500 GB |
| Phone | 442 | Apple | iPhone 12 | P | 256 GB |
| Phone | 112 | Apple | iPhone 13 | P | 256 GB |
| Phone | 453 | Apple | iPhone 14 | P | 256 GB |

```
{
    "Category":"Phone",
    "listofproducts" :[
    {
        "code": "234",
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "model": "Galaxy S21",
        "size": "S",
        "capacity": "500 GB",
    },
    {
        "code": "442",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "model": "iPhone 12",
        "size": "P",
        "capacity": "256 GB",
    },
    {
        "code": "112",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "model": "iPhone 13",
        "size": "P",
        "capacity": "256 GB",
    },
    {
        "code": "453",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "model": "iPhone 14",
        "size": "P",
        "capacity": "256 GB",
    },
    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
out = [
    {"Category": cat,
     "listofproducts": vals.drop(columns="Category").to_dict("records")}
    for cat, vals in pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby("Category")
]  #or if you're using a spreadsheet, use pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Output :

```
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))

[
    {
        "Category": "Phone",
        "listofproducts": [
            {
                "code": 234,
                "brand": "Samsung",
                "model": "Galaxy S21",
                "size": "S",
                "capacity": "500 GB"
            },
            {
                "code": 442,
                "brand": "Apple",
                "model": "iPhone 12",
                "size": "P",
                "capacity": "256 GB"
            },
            {
                "code": 112,
                "brand": "Apple",
                "model": "iPhone 13",
                "size": "P",
                "capacity": "256 GB"
            },
            {
                "code": 453,
                "brand": "Apple",
                "model": "iPhone 14",
                "size": "P",
                "capacity": "256 GB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'Category' with this when I import the file.

Comment: Show your code and your raw csv (*with the separator*).

Comment: I fixed by saving and indicating separator with ";". Thanks a lot!
The only issue now is that it's including a bracket at the beginning and at the end, I can't have it, everything has to be with inside a { } only.

Comment: That's can't be possible if you have multiple categories. Do you have only `Phone` ? If so, use `out[0]` with the code in my answer. Or use : `out = {"Category": "Phone", "listofproducts": pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=";").drop(columns="category").to_dict("records")}`.

Comment: I noticed I made a mistake when asking the question: the field code was a number in the json, when it actually should've been a string like every other field.
That needs to be fixed when generating the json as well.

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", dtype=str)`.